# Devices by 100% usage - How can I solve this problem?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, power-management

I have a Lenovo thinkpad e530 laptop. some device have 100% usage in it. The results of powertop  are in below:

```
Usage     Device name
         10.8%        CPU use
        **100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Conexant
        100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D3: Intel**
         40.0%        Display backlight
         11.0%        Display backlight
        206.2 pkts/s  Network interface: eth0 (r8169)
        162.6 pkts/s  nic:ppp0
        **100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller
        100.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
        100.0%        USB Device: usb-device-8087-0024
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4
        100.0%        PCI Device: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
        100.0%        USB device: TouchStrip Fingerprint Sensor       (UPEK)
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
        100.0%        USB device: USB Optical Mouse**
          0.0 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (brcmsmac)
          0.0 rpm     Laptop fan
          0.0%        Radio device: thinkpad_acpi
          0.0%        Radio device: brcmsmac
          0.0%        USB device: Integrated Camera (C6JC9FCAV)
          0.0%        USB Device: usb-device-8087-0024
          0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
          0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
          0.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means that you have all those devices enabled. So, it says that it's **active** 100% of the time and this is not a problem (on the contrary, it's a good thing).

In fact you should see `man powertop` to see what exactly is the purpose of this command. And see [How to tweak Powertop to reduce power consumption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223250/how-to-tweak-powertop-to-reduce-power-consumption) in this sense.

Comment: Thanks Radu Rădeanu for your answer.

But I have two question:

1- Some device don't have 100% usage (Like "Display backlight" by 40% uage). What is mean it?

2- Some device have 0% usage. How can I enable those?

Comment: @secprog Well, "Display backlight" is not a device, is more likely a property of the display. Some other devices you don't use in this moment; for example, open your camera and you will see that the value attached to "USB device: Integrated Camera (C6JC9FCAV)" will change.

Comment: OK, I thought that is a bug when usage of device be 100% so it's a wrong. I have jut a problem and it's the high temperature of laptop. How can I reduce it?

Comment: @secprog If the answer was useful, you should accept it. If you have other question, use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) buttton. This post can be useful for you, relating to your new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/291496/ubuntu-13-04-high-temperature

Comment: @secprog Also I gave you a useful link in this sense in the answer.